# Laravel Ajax Request returns error 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to create an Ajax request in laravel, but I run into 500 (Internal Server Error). Here is the route that I created:

```
Route::post('/ajaxtest', 'PagesController@update');
```

This is the update function, it currently does nothing.

```
public function update(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    // if ($request->isMethod('post')){    
 //        return response()->json(['response' => 'This is post method']); 
 //    }

 //    return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
}
```

And this is the jquery code

```
function tryajax() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './ajaxtest',
    data: "",
    success: function() {
        console.log("Geodata sent");
    }
})
```

};

There is an onclick function on a button.

Comment: Remove the period from the URL. If it still continues, look at your server logs or in `storage/logs` for a hint.

Comment: also look at the developers tools network tab to see what URL is being called and what's the response

Comment: Unfortunatly, it did not help. There is nothing in the logs also.

Comment: 500s always leave a message somewhere. Did you look at both logs?

Comment: if you are using apache server then, you can look at the error logs. The most common issue I've had personally on laravel with 500 error is _permissions_ with `storage`, `vendor`, and/or `bootstrap` directory in my project (perhaps that is the same issue with yours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to [csrf-protection middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf). You have 2 options: make an exception, or echo a token inside your request.

https://laravel-news.com/excluding-routes-from-the-csrf-middleware

To get you error next time:

- open chrome dev console
- go to network tab
- click the request en view **preview** sub-tab

[image]

Comment: I have the meta tag in the header, and the csrf_field() inside the form.

Comment: But  data is empty, which should be the form-data (also containing the csrf token)

Comment: I figured it out, I deleted Illuminate\Http\ from the function.

Comment: That preview tab tip saved me!

Answer (score 1):

layout:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

script:

```
function tryajax() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: './ajaxtest',
   data: "",
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=\'csrf-token\']').attr('content') }
   success: function() {
     console.log("Geodata sent");
   }
})
```

};

Add csrf-token to request

Comment: so many changes between laravel 4 and 5. so painfull to post an "old" (3 years) site..